# How to get the schema name from the schema object in Tridion?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

As part of implementing the Button to the ribbon tool bar. I require the schema name in the Button java script file. So I am trying to use the following command to get the schema object.

```
$display.getView().getItem().getSchema();
```

The above command will return the schema object. But how to get the schema Title from the schema object. Please help me out in this. Thanks in advance. Early response is appreciated.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Using the following command one can access the schema name.

```
$display.getView().getItem().getSchema().getStaticTitle();
```

Thanks Romkes for your help.

Hey Pufflin I am not saying it is the only solution. But this command is working without any delay. Sorry If I hurt any one's feelings.

Comment: This will still only work if the item is already loaded in a list. Which apparently it was in your testing, but your users are likely to find a situation where the item is not yet loaded. Do yourself and your users a favor and stick to the method that Albert suggested: your code runs in a web UI and the information may need to be fetched from a remote server.

Answer (score 10):

You need to load the item info by calling .load(true) on the schema object. Because (obvious) not all info is loaded because of performance reasons.

Since the .load() call is asynchronous, you have to use a callback function to 'know' when the loading is done.

You can use the following code to load the item and to read it's properties (code simplified):

```
var schemaObject = $display.getView().getItem().getSchema();
function loaded()
{
    alert(schemaObject.getTitle());
}
$evt.addEventHandler(schemaObject, "load", loaded);
schemaObject.load(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is working if put alert in the loaded() method. If not it is returning NULL. It seems it requires some time to load. How to avoid that? Can you please explain me the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't "avoid" that. It's an asynchronous process. Instead you should use events (look at $evt.addEventHandler for instance) to trigger your code to run at the time you need it.

Comment: I would check if getStaticTitle returns anything first, though - the title is one of those properties that might actually be loaded even if the rest of the item isn't (since links to other items typically have the ID and the Title of the target)